# How to remove company field from lead?

Tags: sales

I searched but there is no option to remove company field from lead. I made a look up field for account to relate desired account with lead. so I no need to have company field. But it is required standard field. I am using professional edition. please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You can enable [Person Accounts](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.account_person_enable.htm&type=5), which will allow Company to no longer be a Required Field. Note that Leads without a Company will be converted to a Person Account instead of a Business Account. Be aware that if you enable this feature, there are a [number of considerations you must account for](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.account_person_behavior.htm&type=5). Once you enable this feature, you can never go back.

[image: Non-Required Company Field]

Answer (score 0):

This field `Lead.Company` is required per the [schema](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm)

> Required. The lead’s company.

Comment: Or, enable Person Accounts :D

Answer (score 0):

Standard fields cannot be deleted, and required fields cannot be removed from layouts.

Even though you personally don't have a need for the field, Salesforce does. Your only option is to continue to populate the field.

Comment: Or, enable Person Accounts :D