# Convert Lead to Business Account even when Person Accounts are turned on

Tags: lead-conversion, person-accounts

I need to remove the company name field from the Lead. Our Leads get converted into Business accounts at the moment and that's what I need as our Leads don't contain any contact data and we use related contacts lists to manage contacts with leads.

Leads for our company mean companies we might do business with, and not people in those companies, as we could have many people associated with lead. I understand that in Salesforce that is what an Opportunity is used for, but we don't like to mingle possible accounts and current accounts in our database and so we do not convert until the lead has been won. We do not use opportunities because of this.

I am basing my question on these two other answers:

[How to remove company field from lead?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/369330/how-to-remove-company-field-from-lead)

[Need help on converting person Account to Business Account](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139047/need-help-on-converting-person-account-to-business-account)

My question is if I enable person accounts, can I modify the convert button to still convert leads into business accounts and not person accounts. I'm not a coder, but I can do a little, so if the changes can be made through the UI that would be best.

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T4XmASAV has your answer. Re: _but we don't like to mingle possible accounts and current accounts in our database_  : there are a number of options that would allow you to differentiate a customer account from a prospect account. Simplest: a field on the Account saying so. Out of the box, there's a Type field that can be used for this.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This doesn't work for us. Here is why: when we enter a lead it is ALWAYS a business, never a person. The two required fields for leads are name and company, but since our leads are companies then really these two are duplicates as they would be the same. If I have to put a name in the company field anyway to 
 make a business account there is no point to enable person accounts.

Comment: Quick Action is the typical solution for Leads and required fields: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.predefined_field_values.htm&type=5 . If the lead is a business rather than an individual person, best practice is to avoid the Lead object altogether and create an Account that represents the prospect.

Comment: I had a feeling this was the case. I was hoping for a direct way to modify the convert button itself. but I haven't found a way. I guess I'll just have to create a different lightning pages for leads and accounts and filter according to that field. thanks for the help